# Simple regex excel extraction

Tags: javascript, regex, pentaho, kettle

I got excel with thousands rows like:

```
Basic medical supply - AIT - needs documents from trasnport - drugs
Basic medical supply - TTT - needs documents from trasnport - patiens and other stuff
random string from excel - TTP - other text like always - marijuana per rectum
```

How to set regex to take strings after 3rd "-" character. In this example "drugs", "patiens and other stuff" and "marijuana per rectum".

It cannot be done in jQuery etc. need to be pure JS becasue i am scripting it in Pentago BI. This strings will be very random, only 3 " - " characters are constants. Is possible to do such thing? Maybe take everything to 3rd " - " slice and then save to variable everything left and trim whitespaces and non letter characters?

EDIT:

I have just noticed that in files every second row in this column got products code:

```
550-1008-000000-405.02.04.03
```

Which I have to split too on e.q 550-1028 and 405.02.04.03 so i have to remove those zeros on the middle of string and get 2 substrings

Comment: you can try this withour regex for every string ("Basic medical supply - AIT - needs documents from trasnport - drugs").split("-")[3].trim();

Comment: costName = Hospital.getString();
costName = costName.toString();
costName = costName.split("-)[3].trim();

Comment: Doesnt work at it should becasue mixing with next rows but its closer ;) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the regex could just be `/^.+-.+-.+-\s*([^-]+)\s*$/`

or even easier: `/-\s*([^-]+)\s*$/`

everything after the last "-". Or could that string contain "-" itself?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex does the trick:

```
^([^-]+-){3}(.*)
```

The result is in `$2`, so a standalone code snippet would look like:

```
var s = [
          'Basic medical supply - AIT - needs documents from trasnport - drugs'
        , 'Basic medical supply - TTT - needs documents from trasnport - patiens and other stuff'
        , 'random string from excel - TTP - other text like always - marijuana per rectum'
    ]
  , res
  , i;

for ( i=0; i < s.length; i++ ) {
    res = s[i].replace(/^([^-]+-){3}(.*)/g, "$2");
    console.log ( "#" + i + ": '" + s[i] + "# -> '" + res + "'\n" );
}
```

[live test](https://regex101.com/r/7NaMVS/1) on regex 101.

**Explanation**

The regex is based on a sequence of arbitrary characters except `-`, trailed by a single `-`. It matches 3 consecutive occurrences of this base sequence and assigns the remainder of the line to capture group 2.

**Caveat**

Beware of consecutive `-` chars - this solution is not compatible with such  strings and the proper way to handle that might depend on your data ( eg. may `--` occur as an ascii representation of a dash `—` ?).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a regular expression you can use this:

```
var s = 'Basic medical supply - AIT - needs documents from trasnport - drugs';
var regex = /[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+-(.*)/;
var match = regex.exec(s);
console.log(match[1]); //outputs "drugs"
```

But I'd prefer the solution from @VinodLouis (in the comments) without using regular expressions...

Comment: Every thing almoast works but i wrote in edit another thing which must be included

Comment: @Touche Like you see on the other answers (which ignore the product issue, too) it is not very wise to add other conditions afterwards. I'd suggest you remove the edit text and open another question.

Answer (score 0):

This works simple without any time taking regex

```js
var s = [
          'Basic medical supply - AIT - needs documents from trasnport - drugs'
        , 'Basic medical supply - TTT - needs documents from trasnport - patiens and other stuff'
        , 'random string from excel - TTP - other text like always - marijuana per rectum'
    ];

s.forEach(function(el){
  console.log(el.split("-")[3].trim());
});
```